# NodeJS multiple functions within a module export

Tags: javascript, node.js, module, require

The general idea is that I need a function inside an module.export function. Let's say I have two files: `foo.js` and `math.js`. They are in the same folder.

```
// foo.js
var calc = require('./math.js');

var a = 3, b = 5;
console.log(calc.calc(a, b));
```

It will request an export module to add the two numbers together.

```
// math.js
module.exports = {
    calc: function(a, b) {
        // I need to call another function which does the math right here.
    }
}
```

If I nest them like I tried below, it just returns `undefined`.

```
// math.js
module.exports = {
    calc: function(a, b) {
        x(a, b);

        function x(a, b) {
            return a + b;
        }
    }
}
```

Returns `undefined`.

```
// math.js
module.exports = {
    calc: function(a, b) {
        x(a, b);
    }
}

 function x(a, b) {
     return a + b;
 }
```

Returns `b is not a function`.

How is it possible to nest functions in an export module? I'm new to Node so this might sound like an elementary question, but I really just can't get this to work.

EDIT: This is very simplified. I know I can just do the math in the first calc function, but that isn't possible in my actual code.

Comment: You do not return anything from `calc`, because you miss a `return` in front of the `x(a, b);` call.

Comment: The `b is not a function` error does not match with the code you show.

Answer (score 1):

the **return statement ends function execution** and specifies a value to be returned to the function caller

> in Nested Function

```
module.exports = {
    calc: function(a, b) {
        return  x(a, b);    //Function should Return a Value    
        function x(a, b) {
       return a + b;    
        }
    }
}
```

> in private scoping method

```
module.exports = {
    calc: function(a, b) {
        return  x(a, b);                
    }
}

function x(a, b) {
       return a + b;    
        }
```

> Output

-->foo.js

```
var calc = require('./math.js');
console.log(calc.calc(1,2)); ----> 3
```